# Are Quantum Algorithms that construct another Quantum Algorithm still valid to solve problems in BQP?

Tags: quantum-circuit, complexity-theory, bqp, quantum-turing-machine

The title of this question is somewhat convoluted. Essentially, a problem is in BQP if there is a Turing machine that runs in polynomial time that computes a polynomial depth quantum circuit that solves the problem.

What about something like this:

Suppose we have a polynomial time Turing machine that computes a quantum circuit that computes another quantum circuit. The final circuit solves a problem X. Is X necessarily in BQP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to QCSE.  Your wording is a little informal but I think you are asking whether BQP is "low for itself", that is, if $\mathsf{BQP}^\mathsf{BQP}=\mathsf{BQP}$.

That is, I think you would like to rephrase your question as:

> Suppose we have a polynomial time **classical** Turing machine that **generates a polynomial-size quantum circuit** that **itself calls another polynomial-size quantum circuit**. The final circuit solves a problem X. Is X necessarily in BQP?

The answer is "yes".  Aaronson explains, in his *Quantum Computing Since Democritus*, that this question is [not entirely trivial](https://www.scottaaronson.com/democritus/lec10.html), insofar as garbage must be uncomputed.

Aaronson goes on to explain how recursion wreaks havoc on this uncomputation, but an efficient quantum algorithm calling another efficient quantum algorithm (non-recursively) does not create such headaches.

Comment: Wow, I didn’t know that my question was equivalent to this, but yeah, I can see it is now. Thanks for the answer.